# keras for adding two dense layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

There are two inputs, x, and u, that generate the output y.  There is a linear relationship between x, u, and y, i.e. y = x wx + u wx.  I'm trying to calculate wx and wu from data.  Here is the code for model construction / fitting.

```
    n_train = 400
    n_val = 100
    train_u = u[:(n_train+n_val)]
    train_x = x[:(n_train+n_val)]
    train_y = y[:(n_train+n_val)]
    test_u = u[(n_train+n_val):]
    test_x = x[(n_train+n_val):]
    test_y = y[(n_train+n_val):]
    val_u = train_u[-n_val:]
    val_x = train_x[-n_val:]
    val_y = train_y[-n_val:]
    train_u = train_u[:-n_val]
    train_x = train_x[:-n_val]
    train_y = train_y[:-n_val]

    # RNN derived classes want a shape of (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)
    # batch_size. One sequence is one sample. A batch is comprised of one or more samples.
    # timesteps. One time step is one point of observation in the sample.
    # input_dim. number of observation at a time step.
    # I believe n_train = one_epoch = batch_size * time_steps, features = nx_lags or nu_lags
    # I also thing an epoch is one pass through the training data

    n_batches_per_epoch = 8
    n_iterations_per_batch = round(n_train / n_batches_per_epoch)
    batch_size = n_batches_per_epoch
    time_steps = n_iterations_per_batch
    features_x = train_x.shape[1]
    features_u = train_u.shape[1]
    features_y = train_y.shape[1]

    keras_train_u = train_u.values.reshape((batch_size, time_steps, features_u))
    keras_train_x = train_x.values.reshape((batch_size, time_steps, features_x))
    keras_train_y = train_y.reshape((batch_size, time_steps, features_y))
    keras_val_u = val_u.values.reshape((2, time_steps, features_u))
    keras_val_x = val_x.values.reshape((2, time_steps, features_x))
    keras_val_y = val_y.reshape((2, time_steps, features_y))
    keras_test_u = test_u.values.reshape((1, test_u.shape[0], features_u))
    keras_test_x = test_x.values.reshape((1, test_u.shape[0], features_x))
    keras_test_y = test_y.reshape((1, test_u.shape[0], features_y))

    print('u.values.shape: ', u.values.shape)
    # Now try a tensorflow model
    # x_input = keras.Input(shape=(batch_size, time_steps, features_x), name='x_input')
    # u_input = keras.Input(shape=(batch_size, time_steps, features_u), name='u_input')
    x_input = keras.Input(shape=(time_steps, features_x), name='x_input')
    u_input = keras.Input(shape=(time_steps, features_u), name='u_input')
    da = layers.Dense(ny, name='dense_a', use_bias=False)(x_input)
    db = layers.Dense(ny, name='dense_b', use_bias=False)(u_input)
    output = layers.Add()([da, db])

    model = keras.Model(inputs=[x_input, u_input], outputs=output)

    model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),  # Optimizer
                  # Loss function to minimize
                  loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
                  # List of metrics to monitor
                  metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
    print(model.summary())
    print('keras_train_x.shape: ', keras_train_x.shape)
    print('keras_train_u.shape: ', keras_train_u.shape)
    print('keras_train_y.shape: ', keras_train_y.shape)
    print('keras_val_x.shape: ', keras_val_x.shape)
    print('keras_val_u.shape: ', keras_val_u.shape)
    print('keras_val_y.shape: ', keras_val_y.shape)
    history = model.fit([keras_train_x, keras_train_u], keras_train_y,
                        batch_size=64,
                        epochs=3,
                        # We pass some validation for
                        # monitoring validation loss and metrics
                        # at the end of each epoch
                        validation_data=([keras_val_x, keras_val_u], keras_val_y))
```

And, here is the output, with error.

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
x_input (InputLayer)            [(None, 50, 7)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
u_input (InputLayer)            [(None, 50, 7)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_a (Dense)                 (None, 50, 2)        14          x_input[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_b (Dense)                 (None, 50, 2)        14          u_input[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add (Add)                       (None, 50, 2)        0           dense_a[0][0]                    
                                                                 dense_b[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 28
Trainable params: 28
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
keras_train_x.shape:  (8, 50, 7)
keras_train_u.shape:  (8, 50, 7)
keras_train_y.shape:  (8, 50, 2)
keras_val_x.shape:  (2, 50, 7)
keras_val_u.shape:  (2, 50, 7)
keras_val_y.shape:  (2, 50, 2)
Train on 8 samples, validate on 2 samples

Epoch 1/3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arx_rnn.py", line 487, in <module>
    main()
  File "/arx_rnn.py", line 481, in main
    rnn_prediction = x.rnn_n_steps(y_measured, u_control, n_to_predict)
  File "arx_rnn.py", line 387, in rnn_n_steps
    validation_data=([keras_val_x, keras_val_u], keras_val_y))
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 780, in fit
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 363, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 3292, in __call__
    run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
  File "venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1458, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 2
     [[{{node metrics/sparse_categorical_accuracy/Squeeze}}]]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What is the error message telling me, and how to correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keras categorical accuracy metrics expect the output, & labels, shape as `(batch_size,num_classes)`. The `dim[2]` in error message indicates output shape is 3d: `(None,50,2)`

The simple fix is to ensure, by whatever means, that the output layer gives *one* prediction per class per batch - i.e. has shape `(batch_size,num_classes)` - which can be done via `Reshape`, or `Flatten`.

The better fix is to alter your input-output topology per design needs - namely, *what, exactly, are you classifying?* Your data dimensionality suggests that you seek to classify individual timesteps - in that case, feed data *one timestep at a time*: `(batch_size,features)`. Alternatively, feed timesteps in the *batch axis*, one batch at a time, so 1000 timesteps will correspond to `(1000,features)` - but *do not* do this if model has any `stateful` layers, which treats each batch axis entry as an *independent sequence*.

To classify sequences with `timesteps>1`, again, ensure layer data flow ultimately yields a 2d output.

Comment: The matrices x, u, and y have nt rows, or 595 rows.  Y has two columns, corresponding to 2 outputs.  Both x and u have 7 columns.  x contains previous values of y, making the actual problem stateful, but, as described here, the problem is stateless, since y does not depend on prior rows of x.  The weights wx and wu are known, but I'm trying to calculate those weights using fit.  I'll change the shapes later and report back on the updated status.  The objective is to predict the next value of y.

Comment: "The objective is to predict the next value of y" - in that case, the main, if not only error here is the loss metric; all `categorical` or `accuracy` metrics seldom refer to non-classification. `loss='mse'` is what you need. (see [losses](https://keras.io/losses/) for all metrics)